# Static function not calling in PHP 5.3 Yii Framework

Tags: php, class, yii, static, php-5.3

I've created one controller `CommonController` (not generated by gii) in my Yii App. It contains lot of static methods.

Ex.

```
class CommonController extends Controller{

public static getDate(){
   ...
   ...
}

public static getInfo(){
   ...
   ...
}

etc...

}
```

On Localhost I am using PHP 5.4 and calling static method from another controller/model/view:
Ex.

`CommonController::getDate()`

and its working fine.

Now I've moved app on server which has PHP 5.3 version. I've debugged a lot and found the issue that `CommonController::getDate()` this class is not getting called and its breaking my app.

I've used this stuff everywhere so how can I solve this issue.

Need help.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your error log

Answer (score 0):

You should simply try to import the class before using it :

```
Yii::import('application.controllers.CommonController');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#import-detail

Comment: Is it the issue of php version or issue of yii::import ?

Answer (score 0):

Yii doesn't use its autoloader for controllers. That's why you should import them before using inside other classes.

Anyway, controllers shouldn't be used to share functionalities over other classes in the project. You may create helper classes (under `protected/helpers`) and add them into autoloader (add `'application.helpers.*'` into `import` array of your config file).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the above things and it didn't work for me. So finally I've changed my PHP Version 5.3 to 5.4.10 (which's the stable oldest version) and it worked for me.

Thanks for you help and support.